# Show error information in web form while generating document

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web page that is called from JavaScript using:

```
window.open( url, '_self', ...
```

This ASP.NET page generates on the fly an Excel worksheet so the browser starts downloading it and then opens Excel when it is finished without leaving the caller web page (the one with the JavaScript function).

Now I want to handle all posible errors that might happen while generating the Excel document, catching the exceptions in ASP.NET and showing some error information in a JavaScript alert dialogbox.

I have tried adding in the catch block the following:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Error while generating Excel
> worksheet');</script>");
```

but after accepting the alert window, the browser remains in a blank page. In that situation, I would like to close the alert and remain in the calling web page in the same state as it was when it called the Excel generation ASP.NET page through JavaScript. I have tried using `history.back()` but this reloads the web page losing all changes the user might have done previuosly there.

Comment: I suspect the errors in this case are going to have to be in the "pop-up" window's page.  Though you can certainly provide a better UX than an `alert()`.  Instead of a blank page, you can show some actual HTML with a friendly error message, maybe some information on what the user can try next, as well as a button to dismiss the window.

Comment: @David Thanks for your suggestion. The idea behind using `alert()` is to show the error message maintaining the state of the web page that launches the creation of the Excel document. I agree that it is not an elegant way, but redirecting to an error page will cause to lose all possible changes already made. By the moment, the only possible solution that I see is to open the Excel document in a different window in the browser.

Comment: A different window is fine.  What I'm suggesting is that, when that window's request results in an error, show an error in that window.  Along with a button to dismiss that window.  A friendly error message seems a lot better than a blank window.